# How can I cause a button click to change the image in a picture box?

Tags: vb.net, image

I'm using VS2010 for VisualBasic, and I'm working with several similar forms. What I need to have happen is for the buttonclick on each page to cycle through the My.Resource images in order: adj_01, adj_02, adj_03,... and each form will have a different three-letter prefix.
[This is what I have so far:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjUYq.png)

It might not be clear, but I'm trying to have the images cycle trough one after the other with each button click. Apparently there is an issue with either my referencing, or that the images are .png format. Simultaneously, I'm trying to have 2 separate label update information with each image change. [This is what I have so far with that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Jj9.png)

*EDIT* I just noticed an error that might confuse everyone on the photos: The first lines starting the If statements are checking to see if the PictureBox is empty. Needless to say, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code, not pictures of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
Private Sub NextAdjButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextAdjButton.Click
    If AdjectivesPictureBox.Tag Is Nothing Then
        AdjectivesPictureBox.Tag = 0
    End If

    Dim number As Integer = CInt(AdjectivesPictureBox.Tag)
    If number < 5 Then
        number = number + 1
        AdjectivesPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("adj_" & number.ToString("00"))
        AdjectivesPictureBox.Tag = number
    End If
End Sub
```